# Wordpress - Align image on the left and have text continue on the same indent below the image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an image that I want on the left, so I want the text to be on the right. It works well while the text is still next to the image but once the text gets below the image it wraps and goes to the far left side. I'd like it to stay as if the width of the image extended down farther. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Please put your code (and optionally a screen shot as it'd be helpful) in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for this. But basically you should not just `float` for this construction but rather some columns.

#### Example 1: Flexbox

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container p {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}

.dummy-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="dummy-image"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

#### Example 2: Tables

```css
.two-column-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.two-column-table td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.two-columns-table p {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.dummy-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table class="two-column-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="dummy-image"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
          sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
          duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```